# how to choose a specific single image in GGE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

With this code GGE get the least cloudy image in 2022, but i need to calculate NDVI in a specific image (2022-07-20). What should i change?
If I try to specify a date in filter.Date the code doesn't work.
.filterDate('2022-07-20')

The error is:
NDVI image: Layer error: Image.select, argument 'input': Invalid type.
Expected type: Image.
Actual type: ImageCollection.

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point([8.73727, 45.81165]);

// Import the Sentinel-2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")

// Get the least cloudy image in 2022.
 var image = ee.Image(
 S2.filterBounds(point)
.filterDate('2022-01-01', '2022-12-31')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first()
 );


// Compute the Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI).
var nir = image.select('B8');
var red = image.select('B4');
var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');

// Display the result.
Map.centerObject(image, 9);
var ndviParams = {min: -1, max: 1, palette: ['blue', 'white', 'green']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'NDVI image');
```

Comment: Just ran your code and the error you mention is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The filter function takes as start and end date "ee.Filter.date(start, end)". Since you already know the date you want and Sentinel-2 revist time is not daily (but 10 days), you can apply the filter at a 1-day interval like this:

```
.filterDate('2022-07-20', '2022-07-21')
```